# Is it possible to restrict the number of users per ORG when we set the app expiration date in LMA?

Tags: lma

Is it possible to restrict the number of users per ORG when we set the app expiration date in LMA (License managed Appexchange)?

Comment: Once the app expires, no users can use it at all. What's your use case here?